# Probem with converting a list to an array

Tags: python

I have a problem with converting a list value to an array. For example, I have a list like b.

```
b = [1,2,5,6]
for i in range(5):
    j = np.repeat(i, 3, axis=0)
    b.append(j.tolist())
print(b)
```

and when I run the following code, I got this result:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```

However, I'd like to get:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: try using b.extend(...) rather than b.append(...)

Comment: Thank, I try b.extend(...) and it work!